# Поддержка списка сортированным

Tags: c#

Ваша структура данных будет представлять собой отсортированный список целей, которые будет собирать плюшевый мишка, что сделает его очень эффективным для поиска ближайшей цели и удаления ее, когда она будет собрана. Я знаю, что пространство имен `Systems.Collection.Generics` имеет класс `SortedList`, но вы должны написать свой собственный класс `SortedList`, чтобы вы могли самостоятельно реализовать поддержку отсортированного порядка и чтобы вы могли спроектировать структуру данных для удовлетворения наших потребностей в эффективности.

Мне осталось реализовать метод в классе `SortedList`, описанный в задании

Что я пробовал:

```
public void Add(T item)
{
    int location = 0; while ((location < Count) && (items[location].CompareTo(item) < 0)) { location++; }
    tempList.Clear(); for (int i = 0; i < location; i++) { tempList.Add(items[i]); }
    tempList.Add(item); for (int i = location; i < Count; i++) { tempList.Add(items[i]); }
    items.Clear(); items.AddRange(tempList);
}
```

Этот метод взаимодействует с другим методом:

```
public int CompareTo(object obj)
{

    implementation if (obj == null)
    { return -1; }
    Target otherTarget = obj as Target;
    if (otherTarget != null)
    {
        if (distance < otherTarget.Distance)
        { return 1; }
        if (distance == otherTarget.Distance)
        { return 0; }
        else
        { return -1; }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Во-первых, в подобных учебных заданиях нужно понять, чем разрешено пользоваться, а чем запрещено. Типа, окей, готовым SortedList нельзя, а чем можно? Можно пользоваться List'ом? Нужно написать свою вариацию на бинарном дереве? Во-вторых, вы действительно пишете весь код в одну строку и ломаете глаза каждый раз пытаясь прочитать? Отформатировал по стандарту.

Comment: List’ом пользоваться можно, так же в задании предоставлен tempList, который должен использоваться. Код пишу не в одну строку, но когда вставлял его сюда, он встал криво, честно не знаю почему, извините за это

Comment: Для начала возьмите штатный [List<T>.Sort](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.sort?view=net-5.0) и научитесь сортировать им. Потом переходите к использованию CompareTo - который кстати уже тоже есть готовый: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.int32.compareto?view=net-5.0

Comment: А вообще если прям надо сразу поддерживать сортированность - то надо строить [деревья](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D1%81_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E_%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0)

Comment: Понял, попробую, спасибо за подсказку

Comment: Вообще, вы похоже часть кода не привели. Я думаю, у вас не подойдёт готовый CompareTo - т.к. у вас не int, а какая-то иная структура данных, что-то типа класса Goal c полем Distance (?) Но принцип работы компареров одинаковый - вернуть -1, 0 или 1.

Comment: В задании так же есть пункт реализовать собственный CompareTo, но его я уже реализовал

Comment: Есть вполне себе стандартный алгоритм сортировки вставками. `List<T>` вполне подойдет как хранилище. Берете новый элемент, берете последний индекс элемента в списке, и пока текущий элемент больше вставляемого, уменьшаете индекс на 1. Как только дошли до подходящего места или начала списка, вставляйте новый элемент через `List.Insert`.